# Econometrics : Multiple regression Fisher and Student statistics

Tags: econometrics

I am trying to estimate a production function called Cobb-Douglas.

For the period 1958 to 1972 and for the agricultural sector in Taiwan, we observed:

```
An: Year of observation
Y: Real production in millions New Dollars Taiwan (NDT)
L: Day of Labour, in millions
K: Real Capital in millions de NDT
```

We consider the following model M1: `lm(formula = LY ~ LL + LK)` for = 1958, ..., 1972 where **the variables have been log-transformed.**

1. I try to test H0: $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}=1$ versus H1: $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}\neq 1$  with a Fisher statistic (bilateral test)
2. I try to test the same hypothesis with a Student statistic this time.
3. I try to test (unilateral test) H0: $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}\leq 1$ versus H1: $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}>1$ with a Student statistic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use the delta method to approximate the standard error of $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$:

$$\newcommand{\SE}{\operatorname{SE}}\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}
\SE(\beta_{1}+\beta_{2})\approx \sqrt{\Var(\beta_{1})+\Var(\beta_{2})+2\cdot \Cov(\beta_{1},\beta_{2})}
$$

After the regression command in R, you can type `vcov(model)` which gives you the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients. The values on the diagonal of the variance-covariance matrix are the variances of the respective coefficients while the values off-diagonal represent the covariances between the corresponding coefficients.

With that you can calculate the confidence interval and the $t$-value (for a Wald-test):

$$
t_{\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}}=\frac{(\beta_{1}+\beta_{2} ) - 1}{\SE(\beta_{1}+\beta_{2})}
$$

And from that you can use the $t$-distribution to calculate a two- or one-sided $p$-value with `2*pt(-abs(t), df=n-1)` for a two-sided $p$-value and `pt(-abs(t), df=n-1)`($\leq 1$) and `1-pt(-abs(t), df=n-1)` ($\geq 1$) for the one-sided $p$-values. Please note that the $t$-distribution and the $F$-distribution are closely related: the square of the $t$-distribution with *df* degrees of freedom is the $F$-distribution with 1 numerator degree of freedom and *df* denominator degrees of freedom. It doesn't matter if you use the $t$-value and the $t$-distribution or the squared $t$-value and the $F$-distribution (`pf(t^2, df1=1, df2=n-1)`) to calculate the $p$-values. So I don't know what the difference between 1) and 2) is.

**EDIT:**

The `R`-code for the steps explained above are (it's not the fastest way but I concentrated on legibility):

1) Calculate the variance-covariance-matrix with

```
vcov.mat <- vocv(cobbdoug)
```

2) Calculate the approximate standard error of $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}$:

```
se.b1b2 <- sqrt(vcov.mat[2,2] + vcov.mat[3,3] + 2*vcov.mat[2,3])
```

3) Calculate the $t$-value:

```
t.val <- ((coef(cobbdoug)[2] + coef(cobbdoug)[3]) - 1)/se.b1b2
```

4) Calculate the $p$-value for question 1):

```
2*pt(-abs(t.val), df=cobbdoug$df.residual) # assuming that you have 15 years and 3 coefficients, so df=15-3 = 12
```

5) Calculate the $p$-value for question 3):

```
pt(-abs(t.val), df=cobbdoug$df.residual)
```

Comment: Hi,

I really thank you lots for your complete answer. But what I am looking for are the R codes.

My starting R codes for the Cobb-Douglas function is :

# Cobb-Douglas model
LY=log(Y)
LL=log(L)
LK=log(K)

mco=lm(Y~L+K)
summary(mco)

cobbdoug=lm(LY~LL+LK)

What I would like to know is how to write the R codes for my 3 questions from my first mail.
I already thanks you lots for your answers
Looking forward to reading you

Comment: I forgot to precise that I am "starting" with R.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Hi,Really thank you loads for your quick and very complete answers. Is it normal that when I write the codes in my R console I don't obtain any results except for the 2 p-value ?  
> vcov.mat <- vcov(cobbdoug)
> 
> 
> se.b1b2 <- sqrt(vcov.mat[2,2] + vcov.mat[3,3] + 2*vcov.mat[2,3])
> 
> 
> t.val <- ((coef(cobbdoug)[2] + coef(cobbdoug)[3]) - 1)/se.b1b2
> 
> 
> 2*pt(-abs(t.val), df=12)
        LL 
0.05915371 
> 
> 
> pt(-abs(t.val), df=12)
        LL 
0.02957686

Comment: Yes, that's normal. The other statements are assignements which means that the values are assigned to variable names with <-. I recommend that you consult an [introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) to get familiar with R.

Comment: Thanks,I will have a look at an introduction to R. Thanks one more time for everything.